# Giving NumericStepper's textField a unique id

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to use the NumericStepper component in Flex and would like to give its textField (not just the whole thing) an id but not sure how. I have already given an id to the NumericStepper itself but would like to give an id to its textInput field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It already has one.  The TextInput of a NumericStepper is a skin part named [textDisplay](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/NumericStepper.html#SkinPartSummary).  SkinParts by definition must be defined as public variables.

So you can access it as  `myNumericStepperInstance.textDisplay`

For example to trace out the text, you might use something like this:

```
trace(myNumericStepperInstance.textDisplay.text);
```

I'm not sure what you want to use this for, though.  I'm not sure I'd recommend trying to toy with skin parts from the outside of a component.  You're better off extending the component to perform your needed functionality.

Comment: when I try to test it, I need it to have an id field, and by default it doesn't look like it has one. I can add an id to the whole NumericStepper but not to its textfield for example.

Comment: I'm not sure what you tried to test.  You're going to have to explain what you're trying to do and provide some code.  An ID is the same as the variable name.

Comment: When I say ID I mean the .id attribute (like when you say something.id = unique id;)

Comment: When I say ID, I am referring to this property: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#id which is equivalent to the variable name of component instance.  If you want more help, you're going to have to explain what you want to do and perhaps provide some code.